# how i can force the button text to span multiple lines on small sized screens using Bootstrap 4.0

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, asp.net-core-mvc, media-queries

I have the following code inside my asp.net mvc core web application + bootstrap 4.0, which show a FAQ question:-

```
                     @foreach (var item2 in Model.OrderBy(a => a.Description))
                            {
                                <div class="card">
                                    <div class="card-header" id="@item2.Id+'headingTwoa'">
                                        <h5 class="mb-0">
                                            <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse"
                                                    data-target="#@item2.Id" aria-expanded="false"
                                                    aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item2.Description)
                                            </button>
                                        </h5>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="@item2.Id" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwoa"
                                         data-parent="#accordion" style="">
                                        <div class="card-body">
                                            @Html.Raw(item2.Answer)
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            }
```

but the problem i am facing is that the question description will spell out of screen on small sized screens, while the answer text will align to the screen size.. so not sure how i can force the button text to span multiple lines on small sized screens?

**Edit-1:-**

Here is a markup for a question which spells out of page layout on small sized screens:-

```
<button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#1004" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
What services are being provided?  What if my practice is already performing these services?
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

https://prnt.sc/t3ptin From Bootstrap's official website -> I just added text to the button and it automatically spans on multiple lines
Please, provide screenshots of an actual webpage and HTML code not from your ASP.NET but from the "elements" tab of the browser. I believe you just have a really big word.
If so, check this link(interactive) https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/word-break

**Edit 1**

Just copypasted your button into exact same component on the bootstraps website(https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/collapse/#accordion-example) - https://prnt.sc/t3t7k6 Still works as expected.
It is still hard to give you a clear answer...
I will suggest two things:

1. try too add a `btn-block` class to your buttons
2. provide screenshots of what you have now and also screenshots of the computed props tab https://prnt.sc/t3t9rr 1) select your button 2) switch to computed tab 3) share all the props that browser applies to your button, maybe there is something custom

Comment: updated my question with a markup for a question.. thanks for your reply